# Drag and drop divs

Tags: jquery, css, drag-and-drop, bootstrap-4

```js
$('.component-container').sortable({
  cursor: 'move',
  items: ".component-section",
  placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
  start: function(e, ui) {
    ui.placeholder.width(ui.item.find('.component-section').width());
    ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.find('.component-section').height());
    ui.placeholder.addClass(ui.item.attr("class"));
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fila" class="row center expandir component-container" style="text-align: center;">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12" id="firstCol">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 component-section" id="panel1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 component-section" id="panel3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12" id="secondCol">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 component-section" id="panel2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have made it can be drag and drop. But it has a bug, it allows me to drop three divs in the same column, but it does not allow me to put it back in the empty column.Do you know how can I make to be able to put one of this divs in the empty columns?

Thanks

Comment: `col-xs` is `col` in Bootstrap 4!

Comment: thanks for your correction, however it doesn't fix the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On dragging/dropping a component-section you can check the firstCol and secondCol children using dom. If the number is 2(in your condition given), cancel the drop operation(Can be done with sortable/draggable plugin).

Edit 1: // With the plunker code you have added

```
$('.component-container').sortable({
      connectWith: '.component-container',  // Add this
      cursor: 'move',
      items: ".component-section",
      placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
      start: function(e, ui) {
        ui.placeholder.width(ui.item.find('.component-section').width());
        ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.find('.component-section').height());
        ui.placeholder.addClass(ui.item.attr("class"));
      }
    });
});
```

From html, remove the `.component-container` class from current position and add it to firstCol and secondCol div's

```
<div id="fila" class="row center expandir " style="text-align: center;">  - removed component-container from here


<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 component-container" id="firstCol">  - added component-container here

<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 component-container" id="secondCol">  - added component-container here
```

Comment: Try giving a `min-height` to firstCol and secondCol ?

Comment: This is the most i achieve to do https://plnkr.co/edit/VTGq6hUFlOX3yAlcEJ5T?p=preview

Comment: I have updated the answer. That should be working fine.

Comment: I'm really grateful, It works just perfect. Thanks a lot and best wishes

Comment: Glad it helped! Please, consider accepting my answer.